# Using Ruby's ternary operator ? : to shorten this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ternary-operator

I wonder if there’s a way to tighten this up:

```
def find_by_recordtype
  e = EvLk.find_by_sql(<SQL QUERY>)
  return (e.size > 0 ? e : nil)   
end
```

I could do something like below but, prefer not to query twice.

```
  return ( EvLk.find_by_sql().size > 0 ? EvLk.find_by_sql() : nil)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `find_by_sql` so presumably you're in Rails or have ActiveSupport available. In that case, you can use [`presence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence):

> **presence()**
>
> Returns the receiver if it's present otherwise returns `nil`. `object.presence` is equivalent to
>
> ```
> object.present? ? object : nil
> ```

So you could do this:

```
def find_by_recordtype
  EvLk.find_by_sql(<SQL QUERY>).presence
end
```

Comment: Yes on all assumptions & I knew Ruby would have a more concise way. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is memoize the result.

Whether this makes sense depends on the context of the object and the app.

```
def find_by_recordtype
  return @records if @records

  @records = EvLk.find_by_sql(<SQL QUERY>)
end
```

+1 for ruby nuby.

BTW, why do you want to return `nil`? Usually it's better to the same type for all cases.

Comment: Not sure how memoization is relevant here

Comment: Also, `nil` can be viewed as "instance of the usual type is not available at the moment". "Absent instance", in a sense

Answer (score -1):

```
EvLk.find_by_sql(<SQL QUERY>).tap{|e| break if e.empty?}
```

Comment: I don't like this one-liner. Too confusing :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Most likely, this is an XY-question. This should not be done.